# Opening multiple servers on the same port

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jboss

I am really new to web development. I have installed tomcat v7.0 and jboss v4.2 on my windows7 64bit OS. The editor is Eclipse Juno. I start the Tomcat ( within eclipse ), and type the address

```
  http://localhost:8080
```

It opens me the tomcat welcome page ( the one with the cat ) -- > In IE, Google Chrome.

But the same address opens the Jboss welcome page , when opened in Firefox.

Remember that Jboss is stopped during this whole time.Only tomcat is running

Comment: Try clearing browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

On the same TCP port only one server can listen. Could you write a bit more on your setup? Do you run both tomcat and jboss separately, or you deploy jboss into tomcat? From what you wrote I assume the latter.

Also, are you sure these two pages are on the same url?

Comment: I have added both Jboss and tomcat to the list of servers to use with eclipse for my projects. I run both tomcat and Jboss seperately

Comment: JBoss has it's own Tomcat meaning that if you start both of your servers you will probably end up running two Tomcat instances parallel. If you're new to java servlet web development I'd recommend to start with pure Tomcat as it's a more lightweight container while the other is a full-blown application server, meaning more features and source of problems you don't want to deal with. If you need those features however that's different.